# linear disriminant function error - arguments must be same length

Tags: r

My example dataset:

```
year <- c("2002","2002","2002","2004","2005","2005","2005","2006", "2006")
FA1 <- c(0.7975030, 1.5032768, 0.8805000, 1.0505961, 1.1379715, 1.1334510, 1.1359434, 0.9614926, 1.2631387)
FA2 <- c(0.7930153, 1.2862355, 0.5633592, 1.0396431, 0.9446277, 1.1944455, 1.086171, 0.767955, 1.2385361)
FA3 <- c(-0.7825210,  0.56415672, -0.9294417, 0.21485071, -0.447953,0.037978,  0.038363, -0.495383,  0.509704)
FA4 <- c(0.38829957,0.34638035,-0.06783007, 0.505020, 0.3158221,0.55505411, 0.42822783, 0.36399347, 0.51352115)
df <- data.frame(year,FA1,FA2,FA3,FA4)
```

I then select the data I want to use and run a DFA

```
library(magrittr)
library(DiscriMiner)
yeardf <- df[df$year %in% c(2002, 2005, 2006),] 
yeardfd <- linDA(yeardf[,2:4],yeardf$year, validation = "crossval")
```

But now i get an error telling me the arguments are different lengths.

```
"Error in table(original = y[test], predicted = pred_class) : 
 all arguments must have the same length"
```

I looked at

```
length(yeardf$year)
dim(yeardf)
```

And it looks like they are the same.
I also checked for spelling mistakes as that seems to cause this error sometimes.

- following up on answer.
  The suggested answer works on my example data (which does give me the same error), but I can't quite make it work on my real code.

I first apply the transformation to selected columns in my `data.frame`.  And then I combine the transformed columns with the variables I want to use as groups in my DFA

```
library(robCompositions) 
tFA19 <- cenLR(fadata.PIZ[names(FA19)])[1] 
tFA19 <- cbind(fadata.PIZ[1:16],tFA19)
```

So I think creating my `data.frame` this way must be leading to my error. I tried to insert `stringsAsFactors` into my `cbind` statement, but no luck.

Comment: look at `str(tFA19)` . If you see factors in there, it won't work.

Comment: ahhh! thank you!!  i have converted factors to characters and all is good now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need ,`stringsAsFactors = FALSE` in `data.frame`:

```
year <- c("2002","2002","2002","2004","2005","2005","2005","2006", "2006")
FA1 <- c(0.7975030, 1.5032768, 0.8805000, 1.0505961, 1.1379715, 1.1334510, 1.1359434, 0.9614926, 1.2631387)
FA2 <- c(0.7930153, 1.2862355, 0.5633592, 1.0396431, 0.9446277, 1.1944455, 1.086171, 0.767955, 1.2385361)
FA3 <- c(-0.7825210,  0.56415672, -0.9294417, 0.21485071, -0.447953,0.037978,  0.038363, -0.495383,  0.509704)
FA4 <- c(0.38829957,0.34638035,-0.06783007, 0.505020, 0.3158221,0.55505411, 0.42822783, 0.36399347, 0.51352115)
df <- data.frame(year,FA1,FA2,FA3,FA4,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)


library(magrittr)
library(DiscriMiner)
yeardf <- df[df$year %in% c(2002, 2005, 2006),]
yeardfd <- linDA(yeardf[,2:4],yeardf$year, validation = "crossval")
yeardfd

Linear Discriminant Analysis
-------------------------------------------
$functions        discrimination functions
$confusion        confusion matrix
$scores           discriminant scores
$classification   assigned class
$error_rate       error rate
-------------------------------------------

$functions
          2002  2005  2006
constant  -345  -371  -305
FA1        228   231   213
...
```

Comment: thank you!  My real data is a little different, and though I could reproduce the error with the example data above, the fix doesn't quite work for me.   I will add a few comments to my original text so I can show the code i'm using